# I need help changing my Greeter

Tags: unity, xubuntu, lightdm, unity-greeter

I have Xubuntu xenial, kernel 4.4.25-040425-generic, LightDM GTK+ greeter. The only alteration I've made after the initial install, outside of adding some apps and unsuccessfully trying to get my network controller working (a whole other problem), is upgrading the kernel version from 4.4.0-53-generic. I'm not sure what other information you need, but ask away. HALP PLZ.

I can't seem to change my greeter to the Unity greeter, which is the goal.

Comment: You are asking two things here 1) how to downgrade kernel from 4.4.25 to 4.4.0-53 and also how to change the log-on screen. Do I understand that correctly? If so what is wrong with the current log-on screen (greeter) ie why does it need to be changed? If so what is wrong with the kernel version you are now running ie why does it need to be changed?

Comment: I apologize for the ambiguity. The question is how to change the greeter, other than me not liking the aesthetics of it, nothing is _wrong_ with it. The kernel information is just telling you what I've done since installation.

Comment: split your questions so its more understandable.

Comment: I'm sorry, I only have one question. All the other things were information. the question is how do I change my greeter from GTK+ to Unity

Answer (score 0):

**PART 1: run the following commands in a terminal to install** **`unity-greeter`.**

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install unity-greeter
```

**Reboot your machine.**

If it doesn't use the correct lock screen (display manager), please leave a comment to let me know as you may need additional commands to switch to the correct one.

---

**PART 2: to enable the unity-greeter, run each of the following commands in a terminal**

```
sudo mkdir -p /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/
sudo rm -R /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/*
echo '[Seat:*]' | sudo tee /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-unity-greeter.conf
echo 'greeter-session=unity-greeter' | sudo tee -a /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-unity-greeter.conf
```

**At this point,** save any unsaved work as the next few following commands will log you out and close all open applications:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-artwork
sudo service lightdm restart
```

**Again,** if you do not see the correct login screen before you log in, leave another comment and I will post a fix for that, thanks.

Comment: Done. I still boot into GTK+. How do I tell my xubuntu to stop using GTK+?

Comment: @NuDu Thanks for letting me know, I will post some commands that should fix that in a few moments.

Comment: @NuDu I posted a solution which should now use the unity-greeter. If not, please let me know and I will post one or two more commands to get it to work, thanks!

Comment: @NuDu As for your specific question,  you should be able to tell lightdm to use the unity-greeter by using the file `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-unity-greeter.conf` as the conf file. Because this should be the only file in `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/` it should be the only configuration used. A lot of times, a default configuration file may or may not exist outside of this type of directory but when a configuration file in a `conf.d` directory *does* exist I think the file with the highest number  in that dir is the one that gets priority (or maybe the lowest number but this is only one)